# How to configure Ubuntu with Standard TV?

Tags: nvidia, tv, 8.10

Ubuntu 8 version
nVidia card with driver 96.43.10-0ubuntu1

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Television Screen"
Device "Television Device"
Monitor "Television"
DefaultDepth 24
Option "TVOutFormat" "COMPONENT"
Option "TVStandard" "PAL-B"
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
Modes "640x480@40"
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
    Disable    "dri2"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Default Device"
    Driver    "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Television is Sharp FlatX Standard TV, its specifications can be found at [http://www.amazon.com/Sharp-X-Flat-32F630-Flat-Screen-32/dp/B0000AKVAV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AKVAV)

There were other screen sections which I removed. The TV shows a distorted image with particles of different colors.

I tried different resolutions but couldn't figure it out. Kindly help me set up TV with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [nvidia-settings](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nvidia-settings) [image: Install nvidia-settings]   (Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver)?

I use it whenever I want to connect to a TV.

It configures immediately and generates the desired `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an nVidia graphics card then setting up dual monitors couldn't be easier.

Go to **Terminal** and enter `gksudo nvidia-settings`

That will open the **nVidia X Server Settings** console, click on the **X Server Display Configuration** & from there you can adjust the monitors to suit your needs.

Once you are happy with your monitor setup, click **Apply** then click **Save To X Confuguration File**.

<sub>Unfortunately I'm unaware of how to do this using an ATI graphics card.</sub>

<sub>Editor's note: `gksu/gksudo` are no longer installed by default, but you can install the package. An alternative is to use `sudo -i` to start a root shell, then type the command to launch the application, then `exit` when done to drop privileges</sub>